# Attempt to assign property "referer_uid" on null

Tags: php, laravel

I am currently building a registration system (**with laravel 8**) that check the user register IP to prevent fraud and  create a new instance and save to database if the IP associated does not have prior register record. However, I encountered the following error after posting the registration form to the server.

```
Attempt to assign property "referer_uid" on null
```

I can successfully run the code if I comment out either the $ip_exists or $log_referral. However, they cannot co-exist at the same time.

RegisterController.php

```
<?php
use App\Models\LogReferral;
//...
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'safe_code' => Hash::make($data['safe_code']),
        'register_ip' =>$ip,
        'last_login_ip' =>$ip,
        'referral_code' => Str::random(12),
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
//...
$referer_info = User::where('referral_code',$referer)->first();
$ip_exists = LogReferral::where('ip',$ip)->first();
if(!$ip_exists){
    $log_referral = new LogReferral;
    $log_referral->referer_uid = $referer_info->id;
    $log_referral->referee_uid = $user->id;
    $log_referral->reward = $coin_reward;
    $log_referral->ip = $ip;
    $log_referral->result = "1";
    $log_referral->save();
}
```

log_referrals migration

```
Schema::create('log_referrals', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('referer_uid');
    $table->integer('referee_uid');
    $table->integer('reward');
    $table->string('result');
    $table->string('ip');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**UPDATE**

If a record is existed in $ip_exists, the program will abort with the error above. However, if $ip_exists cannot find any record, everything works fine.

Comment: $user->id; is wrong i guess,. $referer_info has user data

Comment: also $log_referral->ip = $ip; here log_referrals  table missing ip column in migration

Comment: Thanks for the reminder @JohnLobo ! I have updated the code. I can insert to the database successfully if I comment out the line $ip_exists.

Comment: If you comment out everything inside the conditional after the `$log_referral = new LogReferral;`, is it throwing an error?